# "Invalid prop `hasBulkActions` of type `array` supplied to `PureDatagridRow`, expected `boolean`"

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm going through the [react-admin tutorial](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html#mapping-api-endpoints-with-resources) and I keep getting the following error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `hasBulkActions` of type `array` supplied to `PureDatagridRow`, expected `boolean`.
```

I'm new to react-admin (hence the tutorial), and I'm not really sure how to begin going about troubleshooting or isolating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a react-admin error and it has already been fixed in v3.14.3

Answer (score -1):

hasBulkActions  should be a boolean not an array.

I find this sample code from docs:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { cloneElement } from 'react';
import { 
    Datagrid,
    ListBase,
    ListToolbar,
    BulkActionsToolbar,
    Pagination,
    useListContext,
} from 'react-admin';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';

const PostList = props => (
    <MyList {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            ...
        </Datagrid>
    </MyList>
);

const MyList = ({children, ...props}) => (
    <ListBase {...props}>
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        <ListToolbar
            filters={props.filters}
            actions={props.actions}
        />
        <Card>
            <BulkActionsToolbar>
                {props.bulkActionButtons}
            </BulkActionsToolbar>
            {cloneElement(children, {
                hasBulkActions: props.bulkActionButtons !== false,
            })}
            <Pagination />
        </Card>
    </ListBase>
);
```

Comment: How do you change hasBulkActions in any of the react-admin children?

Comment: I tried that today too, even tried just manually overriding "hasBulkActions" to false, and no luck. I'm starting to think it's a bug in the framework.